# NameError: name 'client' is not defined How exactly do I fix this? (discord bot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@client.event
async def on_ready():
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if len(message.content) > 250 or message.author.bot:
        return
    if message.guild:
        messageL = f"{message.author.name.replace(message.author.discriminator, '')} posted: '{message.content}'"
        success1 = await SendHomeMML(messageL)
        if success1 is None:
            print("Message Log message failed.")
        descE = f"{message.author.name.replace(message.author.discriminator, '')} posted: \n'{message.content}'\n" \
            f"This was in a Guild titled '{message.guild.name}' within Channel '{message.channel.name}'\n"
        MessageE = discord.Embed(title="Message Log", description=descE, colour=8421376)
        MessageE.set_footer(text=f"Posted on: {message.created_at.isoformat(' ')}")
        success2 = await SendHomeEML(MessageE)
        if success2 is None:
            print("Message Log embed failed.")
        # and so on...

# Some time later... #

async def SendHomeEML(embedded):
    return await bot.get_channel(xxxxxx).send(embed=embedded)

async def SendHomeMML(message):
    return await bot.get_channel(xxxxxx).send(content=discord.utils.escape_mentions(message))
```

For some reason I keep getting the error

Traceback (most recent call last):
line 4, in 
@client.event
NameError: name 'client' is not defined

Comment: Try `discord.client`?

Comment: Is this your full code?

Comment: Please accept the answer to your question so that people know that it;s been answered.

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize your Discord client. After your imports:

```py
bot = discord.Client()
```

You should also then run the bot, after defining all the functions and hooks:

```py
bot.run('discord_bot_token_here')
```

There is also wrong code in that the `on_ready` block is empty, so... blindly fixing it:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = discord.Client()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    # I moved this line that was hanging around in your main, since it would fail.
    # But you know better where to place it.
    bot.get_channel(xxxxxx).send(content=discord.utils.escape_mentions(message))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if len(message.content) > 250 or message.author.bot:
        return
    if message.guild:
        messageL = f"{message.author.name.replace(message.author.discriminator, '')} posted: '{message.content}'"
        success1 = await SendHomeMML(messageL)
        if success1 is None:
            print("Message Log message failed.")
        descE = f"{message.author.name.replace(message.author.discriminator, '')} posted: \n'{message.content}'\n" \
            f"This was in a Guild titled '{message.guild.name}' within Channel '{message.channel.name}'\n"
        MessageE = discord.Embed(title="Message Log", description=descE, colour=8421376)
        MessageE.set_footer(text=f"Posted on: {message.created_at.isoformat(' ')}")
        success2 = await SendHomeEML(MessageE)
        if success2 is None:
            print("Message Log embed failed.")
        # and so on...

# Some time later... #

async def SendHomeEML(embedded):
    return await bot.get_channel(xxxxxx).send(embed=embedded)

async def SendHomeMML(message):
    return await 



bot.run('discord_bot_token_here')
```

Answer (score 0):

Haha, really simple, you have to define client. Just do this

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="whatever prefix you want")

@client.event()
async def on_ready():
print("Signed In")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if len(message.content) > 250 or message.author.bot:
        return
    if message.guild:
        messageL = f"{message.author.name.replace(message.author.discriminator, '')} posted: '{message.content}'"
        success1 = await SendHomeMML(messageL)
        if success1 is None:
            print("Message Log message failed.")
        descE = f"{message.author.name.replace(message.author.discriminator, '')} posted: \n'{message.content}'\n" \
            f"This was in a Guild titled '{message.guild.name}' within Channel '{message.channel.name}'\n"
        MessageE = discord.Embed(title="Message Log", description=descE, colour=8421376)
        MessageE.set_footer(text=f"Posted on: {message.created_at.isoformat(' ')}")
        success2 = await SendHomeEML(MessageE)
        if success2 is None:
            print("Message Log embed failed.")
        # and so on...

# Some time later... #

async def SendHomeEML(embedded):
    return await bot.get_channel(xxxxxx).send(embed=embedded)

async def SendHomeMML(message):
    return await bot.get_channel(xxxxxx).send(content=discord.utils.escape_mentions(message))
```

Hope this helps you out :)
Remember `client.run("TOKEN")`  as well. :>