# Python discord bot error client.run not working

Tags: python, discord, bots

I wrote this code:

```py
import discord
import os


async def on_ready():
  await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name=" dm for support  ;)"))

client.run("<TOKEN>") 
TOKEN = os.environ['TOKEN']
```

but I keep getting this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "main.py", line 10, in 
> client.run("")
>
> NameError: name 'client' is not defined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NameError: name 'client' is not defined How exactly do I fix this? (discord bot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63517192/nameerror-name-client-is-not-defined-how-exactly-do-i-fix-this-discord-bot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't created the client object you're using, you can create one by doing this before using the client object in your code:

```
client = discord.Client()
```